# What is a positive question record?

Tags: support, specific-question

In the achievement 'Inquisitive', it says that to achieve it you must maintain a 'positive question record'.  What is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/386257) meta post,

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is (TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5. Questions that qualify as Negative *and* Closed *and* Deleted count three times in this calculation!

Answer (score 1):

### Formula

According to the [main meta badge guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/323179), the formula for having a positive question record is:

> `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. Questions that qualify as Negative and Closed and Deleted count three times in this calculation.

### How to find each number

#### Anyone & Everyone

- Look at your [deleted questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current) (found at the bottom of the ["questions tab" on your profile](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions)), and take note of  (1) how many score -1 or less (i.e. "negative"), (2) how many are closed, (3) how many there are total.
- Look at your undeleted questions:

  - Total: [`user:me is:q`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq)
  - Negative: [`user:me is:q score:..-1`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq%20score%3A..-1)
  - Closed: [`user:me is:q closed:1`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20closed%3A1%20is%3Aq)
- Do the math! It works out to something like `((TotalUndeletedQuestions + TotalDeletedQuestions) - (NegativeUndeleted + NegativeDeleted) - (ClosedUndeleted + ClosedDeleted) - Deleted) / (TotalUndeletedQuestions + TotalDeletedQuestions) ≥ 0.5` or even `(TotalUndeletedQuestions + TotalDeletedQuestions - NegativeUndeleted - NegativeDeleted - ClosedUndeleted - ClosedDeleted - Deleted) / (TotalUndeletedQuestions + TotalDeletedQuestions) ≥ 0.5` which looks intimidating but you can do it!

#### Users with ≥2k rep

At 2k rep (10k on some other sites), you get the [moderator tools privilege](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), which allows you to use search to find your deleted posts. This makes the process a lot easier.

- Search for your `TotalQuestions` with [`user:me is:q deleted:all`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20deleted%3Aall%20is%3Aq)
- Search for your `Negative` questions with [`user:me is:q score:..-1 deleted:all`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aq%20score%3A..-1%20deleted%3Aall)
- Search for your `Closed` questions with [`user:me is:q closed:1 deleted:all`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20closed%3A1%20is%3Aq%20deleted%3Aall)
- Search for your `Deleted` questions with [`user:me is:q deleted:1`](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20deleted%3A1%20is%3Aq)

Fun fact: when you search for `deleted:`, you don't need to also use `user:me` — unless you're a moderator.

### Context

The formula for calculating your question record has always been out there, but until 2022 there wasn't a way for the average, low-rep user to figure out what theirs was because they could only see "deleted *recent* questions". Elsewhere you can read about the [whole gory history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/323179) of how this feature evolved.

Comment: I was thinking, what if someone made it easy to run searches like these across SE sites with a stack snippet. And I almost ended up writing it here and now. But I found [this snippet that I already wrote to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324961/323179)! I completely forgot about it and almost wrote it all over again.